# Transferring values between views on rotation - iOS

Tags: ios, rotation, landscape, portrait

Just need some general guidance.

I have programmed my app to switch between two views on rotation. I have done this by way of Apple's advice re Notifications and calling a method to present a modal view of my storyboard Landscape view etc.

My main view consists of two timers, 6 or so buttons, 8 labels and a popover view containing a  Tableview.

The advice I seek is how to best transfer the values between the two views on rotation?

I do have a singleton class setup for transfer of information between the main view and a settings screen. Would I go the same way with this? Put all my data and iVars etc into a singleton class and have the two views access that?

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Regards

Paulh

Comment: So you're modifying Xcode itself?

Comment: I mean, why is this question tagged Xcode? If this is related to Xcode itself, please indicate it - but if it's general iOS/OS X app, please don't use the Xcode tag.

Comment: Oh I see. No Put put Xcode in the title so people would know that it is iOS related. You can't program anything else put iOS with Xcode. Can you change the title? I will change it to iOS if it confuses people?. Update - Changed title now.

Comment: incorrect. Use the iOS tag - that's not confusing. Also, I make iOS apps on Linux without Xcode (in fact, I've made 40+ apps and tweaks without having used Xcode and OS X at all...)

Comment: I stand corrected sir. I've changed the title now so hopefully some kind soul will help me. Regards.

Comment: that's perfect now :) (and +1)

Comment: Just to have it clear: you have a controller A and view B (for portrait) and C (for landscape). Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement a public Method in both views that accepts an `NSDictionary` as an input, and call it in case of rotation (before presenting the modal view).

Put your variables in an `NSDictinary` and pass it to the Method